# My code for an alert will not work when I combined it with the rest of the code for my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

I tested and debugged the code for an alert separately from the rest of my website and it works perfectly when it's separate but when I put the code into my website the alert will not work.

The code for the test website shows an alert saying "this website has fake news", but nothing shows up for the actual website.

I tried to manually debug the code, I tried to debug the code using visual studio code's debugger, and I let my friends look at the code and no one can find an error in the code.

This is some of the alert code for the website:

```
    <div class="popup">The Earth Is Flat
         <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img src="images/fi.jpg">                                        
         <b>ALERT!</b><br>The Blank Device has scanned this website and found Fake News. The phrase "The Earth is flat." is Fake News.</span>
    </div>
```

This is the alert code in the test website where it works:

```
    <div class="popup">The Earth Is Flat
         <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img src="images/fi.jpg"> 
         <b>ALERT!</b><br>The Blank Device has scanned this website and found Fake News. The phrase "The Earth is flat." is Fake News.</span>
    </div>
```

This is the JavaScript code that's in both websites:

```
    function myFunction() {
       var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
       setTimeout(function(){ popup.classList.toggle("show");}, 3000);
    }
```

And this is the CSS:

```
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* The actual popup */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FF0000 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

The code for the test website shows an alert saying "this website has fake news", but nothing shows up for the actual website.

Comment: Where are you calling function myFunction() from ?  You must being doing that width onload or ready or something ?

Comment: @sscotti I'm sorry I just realized I forgot to put it in the question. I'm calling myFunction in the body tag by using the onload event

Comment: @sscotti Your comment just made me realize that I forgot to use onload to call myFunction() in the code of the actual website. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?Logically it would work

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
 <div class="popup">The Earth Is Flat
     <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img src="images/fi.jpg">                                        
     <b>ALERT!</b><br>The Blank Device has scanned this website and found Fake News. The phrase "The Earth is flat." is Fake News.</span>
</div>

   <div class="popup">The Earth Is Flat
     <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"><img src="images/fi.jpg"> 
     <b>ALERT!</b><br>The Blank Device has scanned this website and found Fake News. The phrase "The Earth is flat." is Fake News.</span>
</div>


</body>
```

Did you forget to tnclude the js function in your body tag?